# Azure Active directory with Umbraco 8 not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, umbraco, umbraco-cloud, umbraco8

'UmbracoCms.Core 8.0.0' is not compatible with 'UmbracoCms.IdentityExtensions 1.0.1 constraint: UmbracoCms.Core (>= 7.3.0 && < 8.0.0)'.

Anyone know how to get AzureAD working with Umbraco8?

Answer (score 3):

Umbraco 8 is less than 48 hours old, so you probably shouldn't expect all extensions/packages to be working perfectly at the moment. Maybe go onto our.umbraco.com and ask if anyone else are having the same issues - or, if you are just starting a new project and you need AD integration right now, consider using the latest version 7 instead.